# Optimise SQL Query - Order By Causing Slow

Tags: mysql

I'm finding that when I put an order by on the below table its causing the query to go from 0 seconds to 3.5 seconds (this is only 100,000 rows) Can anyone help me to optimize this?

```
SELECT      offer_id,
        offer_cheapest_rental,
        offer_cashback,
        offer_offertext,
        network_name,
        merchant_image,
        network_image,
        tariff_contractlength,
        offer_link,
        tariff_freemins,
        tariff_freetxts,
        tariff_dataallowance,
        offer_phonecost,
        offer_offerental,
        offer_monthlycost,
        tariff_rental,
        tariff_nicename,
        tariff_name,
        model_imagelarge,
        model_popularity,
        model_make,
        model_name,
        model_colour,
        offer_freegift,
        offer_clearance,
        model_basename,
        p.model_id as model_id,
        type 
        FROM deals_temp d
        INNER JOIN phones p ON d.model_id = p.model_id 
        INNER JOIN tariffs t ON d.tariff_id = t.tariff_id 
        INNER JOIN networks n ON d.network_id = n.network_id 
        INNER JOIN free_gift fg ON d.freegift_id = fg.freegift_id 
        INNER JOIN merchants m ON d.merchant_id = m.merchant_id 
        INNER JOIN type ty ON ty.type_id = d.type_id
          ORDER BY deal_popularity DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Do you have an index on deal_popularity? If not, that is your answer, though you should certainly expect that a sorted query would take longer than unsorted.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/

Comment: Use indexes with InnoDB.

Comment: Yes deal_popularity has an index...and im using InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT      offer_id,
    offer_cheapest_rental,
    offer_cashback,
    offer_offertext,
    network_name,
    merchant_image,
    network_image,
    tariff_contractlength,
    offer_link,
    tariff_freemins,
    tariff_freetxts,
    tariff_dataallowance,
    offer_phonecost,
    offer_offerental,
    offer_monthlycost,
    tariff_rental,
    tariff_nicename,
    tariff_name,
    model_imagelarge,
    model_popularity,
    model_make,
    model_name,
    model_colour,
    offer_freegift,
    offer_clearance,
    model_basename,
    p.model_id as model_id,
    type 
    FROM deals_temp d
    INNER JOIN phones p ON d.model_id = p.model_id 
    INNER JOIN tariffs t ON d.tariff_id = t.tariff_id 
    INNER JOIN networks n ON d.network_id = n.network_id 
    INNER JOIN free_gift fg ON d.freegift_id = fg.freegift_id 
    INNER JOIN merchants m ON d.merchant_id = m.merchant_id 
    INNER JOIN type ty ON ty.type_id = d.type_id
) a
ORDER BY deal_popularity DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself by using `FORCE INDEX (deal_popularity)` and it's running much quicker now:

```
SELECT offer_id,
        offer_cheapest_rental,
        offer_cashback,
        offer_offertext,
        network_name,
        merchant_image,
        network_image,
        tariff_contractlength,
        offer_link,
        tariff_freemins,
        tariff_freetxts,
        tariff_dataallowance,
        offer_phonecost,
        offer_offerental,
        offer_monthlycost,
        tariff_rental,
        tariff_nicename,
        tariff_name,
        model_imagelarge,
        model_popularity,
        model_make,
        model_name,
        model_colour,
        offer_freegift,
        offer_clearance,
        model_basename,
        p.model_id as model_id,
        type 
        FROM deals_temp d FORCE INDEX (deal_popularity)
        INNER JOIN phones p ON d.model_id = p.model_id 
        INNER JOIN tariffs t ON d.tariff_id = t.tariff_id 
        INNER JOIN networks n ON d.network_id = n.network_id 
        INNER JOIN free_gift fg ON d.freegift_id = fg.freegift_id 
        INNER JOIN merchants m ON d.merchant_id = m.merchant_id 
        INNER JOIN type ty ON ty.type_id = d.type_id
```